# R Shiny - Using a slider value to no decimal places

Tags: r, shiny

When using a slider in Shiny, the value shown is to 3 decimal places and I was wondering if there was a way to explicitly tell the slider to jump in whole numbers?

**ui.R - snippet**

```
#Slider from 1 to 3570
sliderInput(dataIn_labels[1],
                      "Probes:",
                      min = 1,
                      max = length(dataIn[[1]][,1]),
                      value = 50)
```

Comment: There's a `round` option.

Comment: For anyone that comes across this, `round` seems to mess up conditional panel formatting. I used `step = 1` and that did the trick

Comment: The sliders are generally quite sensitive to placement and options. I've had a few examples where the first slider is displayed correctly but the later ones incorrectly. Even after changing the order, the top ones were displayed correctly and the bottom ones incorrectly. It's a relatively new project, there's still a lot to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `round=TRUE`. From the help (`?sliderInput`):

> round: ‘TRUE’ to round all values to the nearest integer; ‘FALSE’ if
>             no rounding is desired; or an integer to round to that number
>             of digits (for example, 1 will round to the nearest 10, and
>             -2 will round to the nearest .01). Any rounding will be
>             applied after snapping to the nearest step.

In your case, you then have:

```
#Slider from 1 to 3570
sliderInput(dataIn_labels[1],
                      "Probes:",
                      min = 1,
                      max = length(dataIn[[1]][,1]),
                      value = 50,
                      round = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to round, there is also the `format` option. You can use that to control the appearance of the numbers. For your slider use:

```
#Slider from 1 to 3570
sliderInput(dataIn_labels[1],
                  "Probes:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = length(dataIn[[1]][,1]),
                  value = 50,                 
                  format="####")
```

The four #s mean you will have four digits and no decimal. If you used `####.#` instead, it would show as four digits, and then one after the decimal. For details see `?sliderInput`.